# fuse.js return specific item from nested json object

Tags: javascript, json, fuzzy-search, nested-object, fuse.js

I am using [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) to fuzzy search a json dataset that looks something like this:

```
const dataSet = [
    {
      title: "a list",
      cards: [
        {
          title: "a card",
        },
        {
          title: "another card",
        },
        {
          title: "a third card",
        },
      ],
    },
...
];
```

When I perform a search for a card title:

```
const fuse = new Fuse(dataSet, { keys: ['cards.title']})
console.log(fuse.search("a third card"))
```

the list that contains the card is returned

```
{
   title: "a list",
   cards: [
      {id: 1, title: "a card"},
      ...
   ]
}
```

I want the data to return the specific card that has the title "a third card". Is there any way I can do this?

I looked into the docs, and found a [`getFn`](https://fusejs.io/api/config.html) option that might do the job, but I couldn't get it to work. I also know that I can achieve this by flattening my object, but I don't want to do that as it adds complexity for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you could do is set the option [`includeMatches`](https://fusejs.io/api/options.html#includematches) to `true`. This would also give you the exact item that was matched in the nested sub-array.